# RabbitMQ Queues HA and Dead Letter Exchanges Not Working

Tags: rabbitmq

I have 3 nodes (A,B,C) in my cluster . Right now I want to configure the queue High Availability using the ha-nodes option with nodes A and C as the params.I am successfully configured the HA policy and its working. 
But after I use the DLX policy for all queues, the HA policy is not working anymore. 

Is that normal or am I missing something here?

I want to use the HA policy and DLX policy together, but now it seems impossible.
 Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one policy is applied at a time for a given queue or exchange:
http://www.rabbitmq.com/parameters.html#policies

But you still can configure HA and dead-lettering together: you just need to do that in one policy. Here is an example:

```js
{
  "ha-mode": "nodes",
  "ha-params": ["A", "C"],
  "dead-letter-exchange": "my-dlx"
}
```